# django 1.6 When creating superuser in cmd.exe, why ask password for three times?

Tags: django

django 1.6.1,python 3.3.3, windows 8.

I choose [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user), and everything is ok except creating superuser at the beginning:

[image]

As you can see, django asked password for three times, why?

[this is the source code](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c0lA5JM), if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be that I should not add 'password' to REQUIRED_FIELDS.

More infomation please [click](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/eClJxZl5tmA)